# Webview zoom not focussed and child view ovelaps

Tags: android, webview, google-inbox

I am trying a view similar to conversation view in Inbox app for gmail android app.

They have used `RecyclerView` for multiple webviews. So I added multiple webviews inside recycler view. The click events are passed to the webview. But I cannot zoom the webview.

Previously I added multiple webviews inside scrollview. I used `NonLockingScrollView` from here [https://zi.is/p/browser/k-9/src/com/fsck/k9/view/NonLockingScrollView.java?rev=e4d26b8c752f03dc8a40bcb59a0e601835205083] . I was able to zoom correctly, but the adjacent child views are not adjusted according to the zoom.

How can we achieve this effect? Any hint would be greatly helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for built-in zoom support, this would solve that:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Good luck,'.

Comment: Sorry pal, I am using this for zooming. The problem is, during the time of zoom, other views are not expanded.

Comment: @arul other views means, they are part of webview ?

Comment: @krunalshah no. They are views above and below webview. In case of inbox mail app, it is subject and attachements at the bottom.

Comment: @arul so you have to use concept of multi-touch pinch zooming.